# Format text fields as local file links in Dynamics CRM 2015 on premise

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

What I'm trying to do is create a hyperlink to a local folder on an Opportunity form.

AFAIK, there're two appropriate ways to format such data:

1. Using text type
2. Using URL type

The problem is when you paste a link to local resource, like `\\filestore\folder1`, the URL formatter prepends it with `http://` creating a hyperlink `http://\\filestore\folder1` (which doesn't work) instead of `file://\\filestore\folder1` (which works correctly).

Previous solution like creating a text field storing link text (`\\filestore\folder1`), and a button on a form. Using button onclick event and passing text field value as URL parameter by manipulating the DOM stopped working after on premise rollup 1.

Any suggestions how to do it now?

Comment: create a webresource that will take the value from the text field and display an html link to the local resource

Comment: In general web browsers are not allowed to directly access local folders, due to security issues. You can only accomplish this indirectly using ActiveX or other plugins or through intermediate components.

Comment: Guido, I've tried creating a web resource, and grabbed the link text from the source field, but failed to pass it to the target location. Any heads up on how to pass it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I couldn't pass the field value down to target web resource from the form. I've managed to solve the issue by accessing parent CRM page form field by using `parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute()`. Everything works correctly now.